# Understanding Standard Error ($\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$) from the definition

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

In the "normal" sense, I have understood standard error to be the standard deviation of the means. Hence, you would need to calculate multiple averages ($\bar{x}_1,..., \bar{x}_n$) and calculate the standard deviation (let $u$ be the average of the average):

$$SE = \sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (\mu - \bar{x}_i)^2}{n-1}}$$

I do not understand how this eventually becomes $(1) \ SE = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ . Afterall, don't you need multiple averages to get this value? How are we able to calculate it with just one set of data? An explanation on how $(1)$ is derived would be greatly appeciated.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error?wprov=sfla1).  The standard error (SE) of a statistic (usually an estimate of a parameter) is the standard deviation of its sampling distribution or an estimate of that standard deviation.

Comment: In the case of the sample mean we have $\mathrm{std}(\bar X_n)=\sigma/\sqrt n$.

Comment: You are correct that you can estimate the standard error of the sample mean by taking the standard deviation of multiple means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $X_i$ are i.i.d. with expectation $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and you take a sample size $n$ then the mean $\bar X$ is distributed with expectation $\mu$ and variance $\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$.  The square root of that variance is then the standard error of the mean and is $\sqrt{\mathbb E\left[(\bar X-\mu)^2\right]} = \sqrt{\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}}=\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$.

If you do not know $\sigma^2$ then you may want to estimate the standard error from your observations.  Your expression is a possible approach based on taking multiple samples, so if you took $m$ of these (not the same as $n$) then you could use $\sqrt{\dfrac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m} \left( \bar{x}_j - \overline{\bar x}\right)^2 }{m-1}}$, but this would involve $mn$ observations as well as averages of averages.

Alternatively, you could use one sample size $n$ to estimate $\sigma^2$ perhaps with $\dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} ({x}_i-\bar x )^2$, and thus estimate   $\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$ using $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} ( {x}_i-\bar x )^2}$.

Comment: So the SE is not exactly the standard deviation of the means, but rather the square root of the average variance of the dataset?

Comment: @A.RadekMartinez The standard error of a sample statistic the square root of the variance of the distribution of that statistic (here the sample mean).  Typically you do not know this so attempt to estimate it from the sample.